# Demonstrate $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \cos^{2k}(\theta)\,d\theta = \frac{(2k)!}{2^{2k} (k!)^2}$ (problems with the hints)

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, residue-calculus, laurent-series

So I have to prove

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \cos^{2k}(\theta)\,d\theta = \frac{(2k)!}{2^{2k} (k!)^2} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\forall k \in \mathbb N \,\cup \{0\}$$

Following the next hint:

$\textbf{First, prove}$

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{w+\cos(\theta)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{w^2 - 1}}$$

$\forall w\in \mathbb C -[-1,1]$

(This part is realtively easy, using the residue theorem)

$\textbf{Then, expand each member of the equality in power series centered at $\infty$}$

This second hint is confusing; basically, I don't know how to express the Laurent series for both functions at a neighborhood of infinity (that doesn't contain the line segment $[-1,1]$).

I know there are solutions to the main problem, but I have to use the given hints, and I am very interested in the calculation of the Laurent series of the formulas given above, and how could those help me prove the main statement.

Thanks in advance for trying to solve this

Comment: Note the proper way to typeset $\cos,$ as in my edits to this question, and the fact that $$\mathbb N \cup \{0\}$$ does not require the use of \text{}. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{w+\cos\theta}
&=w^{-1}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{1+w^{-1}\cos\theta}
=\int_0^{2\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n w^{-n-1}\cos^n\theta\,d\theta\\&
=\sum_{m=0}^\infty w^{-2m-1}\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^{2m}\theta\,d\theta
\end{align}
as the integral of $\cos^n\theta$ vanishes for even $n$.

Comment: That is accurate, and gives some way to express the Laurent series for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$, but I don't know how to actually calculate those $a_n$, which are the $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} cos^{2k}(\theta)d\theta$. Using the usual formula to calculate those doesn't seem to help. I found out, using the fact that $|w| < 1$ that $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} = \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^\infty w^{-2k}} $ , but I don't know how to proceed in order to set the values of $a_n$

Comment: @VíctorVela For the other side, just use the binomial theorem.

Comment: How can I use the binomial theorem? There is a square root involved, and I have never used the theorem for that kind of functions

Comment: @VíctorVela https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalized_binomial_theorem